# Заменить фразу по слову

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Данная конструкция заменяет лишь одно слово из фразы:

```
$istok = "шерсть яка";

$vivod = preg_replace('/\bяк(а)\b/iu', 'як', $istok);

echo $vivod;
```

*(здесь результат будет: "шерсть як")*

пример: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fbf737865909307ff082811655e90e72cc2e4035

Задача: **заменить фразу целиком** на нужное слово, т.е. на выходе, вместо фразы "шерсть яка" получить "як".

Как этого добиться?

Comment: проверить если есть вхождение в строке (используя [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)), то удалите всю строку и вставьте в нее "нужное слово"

Comment: Логика понятна. Но был бы благодарен за живой пример. с его составлением трудности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Набросал пример на коленке

```
$istok = "шерсть яка";

$vivod = preg_replace('/.*\b(як)\b.*/iu', '$1', $istok);

echo $vivod;
```

Comment: Нашел нюанс - в данном примере замена происходит при нахождении любого слова с "як". Например слово "кожемЯКа" заменит тоже. Не могли бы вы поправить пример, что бы замена происходила только по указанному слову?

Comment: Дописал в шаблон символ пробела перед искомым словом.

Comment: Спасибо! Но также проблема и с окончанием. Сейчас заменяет слова которые начинаются на "як". например "якорь" заменит. (прошу прощения что по таким деталям прошу правки, но с регулярками пока вообще не дружу..

Comment: Дописал символ границы слова после искомого слова.

Comment: обнаружил еще один нюанс - если в исходном не фраза, а одно слово, то замена не происходит. Либо, если искомое слово стоит первым во фразе, замена тоже не происходит..

Comment: Подкорректировал.

Answer (score 1):

Работает только с указанными словами. В противном случае возвращает фразу без изменений.

```
$array = [
    "яка" => "як",
    "альпаки" => "альпака",
];

$istok = "шерсть альпаки";

$vivod = preg_replace('/.* ([^ ]*)/iu', '$1', $istok);

if (isset($array[$vivod])) {
  $vivod = $array[$vivod];
} else {
    $vivod=$istok;
}

echo $vivod;
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Но решение не универсальное. На деле, конечно, фразы, которые потребуется заменять, будут разными (шерсть альпаки, натуральная кожа), соответственно, необходимо иметь возможность вручную указать слово, по которому будет находится фраза, и слово/фразу, на которую оно будет заменяться

Comment: @Amsterdam в чем проблема? напишите из данного примера функцию, которая будет принимать ваши разные фразы и разные подстановки и просто в функции подставляйте вместо того, что вам показали (вместо того что вам жестко вбили)

Comment: Это нужно было сразу писать. Я поправил решение.